# How do I pass Cypress arguments to a NPM e2e build job?

Tags: cypress

How do I pass Cypress arguments to a NPM e2e build job?

I tried something like this but I cannot get variables to expand:

```
USERNAME=$EMAIL PASSWORD=$SECRET ng e2e --config-file=dev-cypress.config.ts
```

I also tried this:

```
ng e2e -- --USERNAME=$EMAIL --PASSWORD=$SECRET --CYPRESS_CONFIG_FILE=dev-cypress.config.ts
ng e2e --USERNAME=$EMAIL --PASSWORD=$SECRET --CYPRESS_CONFIG_FILE=dev-cypress.config.ts
```

And I tried this:

```
CYPRESS_CONFIG_FILE=dev-cypress.config.ts USERNAME=$EMAIL PASSWORD=$SECRET ng e2e
```

What am I missing?   Whatever I try, the Cypress "effective configuration" does not expand the env variables correctly (at all)

Here is my build config in my `angular.json` config:

```
....
"e2e": {
    "builder": "@cypress/schematic:cypress",
    "options": {
        "devServerTarget": "pas-ng-xdm:serve",
        "watch": true,
        "headless": false
    },
    "configurations": {
        "production": {
            "devServerTarget": "pas-ng-xdm:serve:production"
        }
    }
}
```

NOTE: Using a npx cypress command, that works for me:

```
"cypress:run:dev": "npx cypress run --config-file dev-cypress.config.ts --record 
 --key 0000000-e33c-4c88-9ead-1d0000000c --browser chrome --headless",
```

NOTE 2:  When using the `ng e2e`, my only option is to allow it to load the default `cypress.config.ts`.  Maybe that is ok:  perhaps this is working as designed?

Comment: Just to clarify, when you say that's your `package.json` do you actually mean your `angular.json`?

Comment: Yes, i mean angular.json .   I suspect what I am doing is "as designed", where e2e means "testing locally only, not flexible to different envs" ??   I guess my question is probably about the angular schematic, and how it functions.   Maybe a way to pass args using the `configurations` section in the e2e build config?

Comment: Cypress tests can access environment variables that start with CYPRESS_. For example, you define a variable CYPRESS_USERNAME for your user in your shell. Then it is available in your test under Cypress.env("USERNAME"). Maybe that will help. Otherwise, the other options are described [here](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/environment-variables#Option-3-CYPRESS_).